# Where is Ebizmarts/MageMonkey/Block/Lists.php used?

Tags: magento, mailchimp

There is a file in the magento magemonkey plugin, here:

```
app/code/community/Ebizmarts/MageMonkey/Block/Lists.php
```

What is it for? Where is it used?

I can find no evidence of it being included anywhere, but it calls some functions that I need to modify, so I need to know how to access it for testing.

So, is it used anywhere? How do I trigger it?

**Or**

can I safely delete this file without affecting anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the 3 component of an MVC framework, Model, View and Controller, then the above is a block file which when combined with a .phtml template file equates to the View portion of MVC.

In Magento, the View is instantiated through layout XML files within each module which define both blocks, and templates, and these can be page specific by layout handle.  In order to determine if the above block is in use you would need to find if there are any references to the block in any of the layout files, which I'm guessing there will be in any layout file defined by that module.

I will add that I would **never** recommend just deleting a file in any module unless it is a module you have created and you know what you are doing in deleting it.  The reason for this is that Magento is a configuration based framework and so every resource is defined somewhere.  For this reason you *will* you break something if you start removing files without first defining that resource as no longer being required in the configuration.

Going by what you have said above, it sounds like you need to learn quite a bit more about the Magento system as a whole and in particular rewrites before going any further.  Unfortunately there isn't sufficient room here to explain all the way from the basics to the point of being able to construct and alter your own modules here - we would literally be here all day.

Answer (score 0):

The block is used to populate different lists from MailChimp you can see it inside the module files, for example **class Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Block_Customer_Account_Lists extends Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Block_Lists**

May I ask why would you delete it? Is it causing any problems?

Thanks!